# Proof of a bounded function via Big O notation

Tags: proof-verification, upper-lower-bounds

I want to proof for a given function, that some other function is an upper bound of the given function. For example, given is the function:

$f (n) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{lll} 
\frac{1}{2log(n)}-2n+2^n  &\textrm{n>42 and odd} \\ 
(\frac{7}{2})^n + \frac{3}{4}n^2 - log(n) &  \textrm{n ≤ 42} \\ 
 \frac{3^n}{n^3} - (n+1)^3 + log(2^n) & \textrm{otherwise}\\ 
\end{array} 
\right.$

I now want to check with the Big O definition:

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty}$

if $n^2$ or $e^n$ is an upper bound or not.

This should be an easy task, however I'm also a little bit unsure how to handle the cases. If I can proof that one case is not an upper bound, does this proof that the whole function can't be an upper bound?

Comment: Yes, that proves it, assuming the case is the first or last one (i.e. involves arbitrarily large $n$). You can essentially ignore the second case since we are looking at a limit as $n\to \infty$, and values of $f(n)$ for $n\le 42$ (or any constant value) do not affect this limit.

Comment: That is NOT the definition of big-O. We write "$f(n)=O(g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$"  to mean that there exists $K>0$  and there exists $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $\forall n>x\,(|f(n)|\le K|g(n)|).$ It is not necessary that $f(n)/g(n)$ converges as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: My edit was for  typo. You had f(x) for f(n) in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the three cases you present, there are actually only 2 that interest us, the first and third.

This is because you want to test for asymptotic limits when $n$ becomes large, and the second case only deals with the first elements of the function, so it's not important for the limit.

However, for the first and last case, then yes, both of them have to be bounded in order to be able to say that $f=O(g)$.

The way I simplify it in my mind is that I just think of it as a sequence $u_n$ defined via $f$. Then you do have to bound all the cases to bound the sequence.